# git status : bad config value for 'core.autocrlf' in .git/config

Tags: git

I am getting the following error on doing the following

```
$ git status
fatal: bad config value for 'core.autocrlf' in .git/config
```

I get the same result with `git branch` or any other command
Any suggestions on what the cause might be ?

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
    autocrlf = =
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@mst-git:tgi-common/gcmmon.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[submodule "Experience"]
    url = git@mst-git:tgi-windows-os/exp.git
[submodule "Module"]
    url = git@mst-git:tgi-general-tools/module.git
```

Comment: Can you post your .git/config  (`more .git/config `)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you did it, but basically remove the line in the file that says

```
 autocrlf = =
```